# What are the main security features in Dart?

Tags: dart

Some Dart articles and references mention that Dart has good security features but don't specify them.

What are the main security features in Dart?

Comment: obscurity enhances security; look at the number of windows vs mac viruses...

Comment: The document linked doesn't really talk about security features, it just says that it is designed to be securable.

Comment: @PeeHaa I up-voted that comment as I was away to say the same thing but have you actually read the citation? At a cursory glance it barely mentions security.  From what I gather it's not so much the language itself that's *"more secure"* but the encouragement of the usage of some - unspecified - patterns that might stop a programmer doing something stupid.

Comment: @Emissary So you are telling me the cake is a lie basically?

Comment: @PeeHaa The link takes me to https://gist.github.com/paulmillr/1208618. I may've missed something, but I couldn't find any specific security features mentioned there. The email only mentions this: "Dash [Dart] is also designed to be securable, where that ability does not seriously conflict with the three main goals"

Comment: @PeeHaa I'm saying wiki might not be totally trustworthy source of information.

Comment: Google's been trying to push Dart for a while, that document is several years old - would have thought there'd be a more definitive answer out there if there really was any fundamental difference in regards to security.  It's my understanding that Dart requires it's own VM installed which (and I'm no expert) sounds like a can of worms - in any case there's nothing inherently insecure about Javascript in modern browsers is there?

Comment: @Emissary Well Javascript-based attacks have been shown time and again, even in non-IE Firefox. In particular I recall heap-spraying and use-after-free as types of attacks, but I don't really know anything more than those names. I guess Dart might have a structure which makes those less likely.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for this excellent joke; it almost made my day. "Security by obscurity", and Win vs Mac as an example -- priceless...

Answer (score 2):

Dart has automatic HTML sanitization. For example, if you try to do this:

```
element.innerHtml = '<script>haxor</script>';
```

Dart will strip the `<script>` tag for you. The developer has to work hard to opt-out of this feature.

Dart VM supports isolates, a way to more securely run untrusted code. An isolate can't access other isolates, it can only send and receive messages. Those messages are copied before they are received, to ensure state is isolated.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the dart runtime is also isolated; but this would only apply to chrome as its the only one that has a dart runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I did a cursory look through the dart specification (including some ctrl-f), and the only mention of security I found was

> Privacy is, at this point, a static notion tied to a particular piece of code
> (a library). It is designed to support software engineering concerns rather than
> security concerns. Untrusted code should always run in an another isolate. It is
> possible that libraries will become rst class objects and privacy will be a dynamic
> notion tied to a library instance.

It might worth [searching for security on the Dart website](https://www.dartlang.org/search.html?cx=011220921317074318178%3Ai4mscbaxtru&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&q=security), but to be honest I'm not really finding anything, nor do I see any claims that they are trying to make it more secure than JavaScript.

---

So basically, I'm not sure it is more secure, or that anyone ever claimed it was.